# Is 2-SAT an instance of SAT? Why Shannon's Theorem does not imply that some Boolean formulas (instances of SAT) require exponential size circuits?

Tags: computational-complexity

**Question 1:** SAT is defined as a language of all satisfiable boolean formulas. Does definition of SAT imply that all 2-SAT instances are instances of SAT? If 2-SAT is an instance of SAT, why is it not NP-complete?

**Question 2:** Chapter 6 (Boolean circuits) of *Computational complexity* by Arora and Barak. Every Boolean function can be expressed by a Boolean formula. SAT is defined as a language of all satisfiable boolean formulas. By Shannon's Theorem, for every $n$>1, there exists a function *f*: {0,1}$^n$ $\rightarrow$ {0,1} that cannot be computed by a circuit $C$ of size 2$^n$/(10$n$). Why does not Shannon's Theorem imply that there are SAT formulas that are not computable by polynomial size circuits?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Regarding question 2: what do you mean by "SAT formulas that are not computable by polynomial size circuits"? Polynomiol in what? What is the computation? Clearly with $n$ variables, you can write boolean formulas of size exponential in $n$.

Answer (score 1):

**Question 1:** Yes, 1SAT and 2SAT (satisfability of boolean formulas in CNF with at most 1 or 2 literals per clause) are special cases of SAT (satisfability of boolean formulas). But they are easy: 1SAT is trivial (if both a variable and it's negation appear, non satisfiable; else satisfiable), 2SAT can be solved in linear time too by [Krom's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2-satisfiability). But the general case is hard, in fact NP-complete.

Comment: SAT is NP-complete because instances of every NP language can be Karp reduced to instances of SAT. Since instances of 2-SAT are instances of SAT, instances of any NP language are Karp reducible to 2-SAT as well. So, 2-SAT should be NP-complete. Why is it not the case?

Comment: got it: since Karp reduction from A to B is not a bijection between languages A and B, instances of any NP language are not necessarily mapped to a unique and every SAT instance. It has not been shown that any instance of any NP languaged can be mapped to a 2-SAT instance by Karp reduction.